# how to force the network captive page to show up again

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, captive-portal

I got into a hotel that has two wifi options: standard and premium. the first time i connected to the hotel wifi (on mac) it showed me the default captive page. I went with the free one.

However I later on purchased the premium card.. but now I have no idea how to make that captive page show up again since it simply re-logs using the free account. Any idea how I can force it to show the captive page again? I already erased cache etc of chrome/safari.. no luck

## update

so the network is called citymax.. i found this in

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist 

    <key>wifi.ssid.&lt;43495459 4d4158&gt;</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AutoLogin</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Captive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ChannelHistory</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Channel</key>
                <integer>161</integer>
                <key>Timestamp</key>
                <date>2016-10-07T20:46:51Z</date>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Channel</key>
                <integer>149</integer>
                <key>Timestamp</key>
                <date>2016-10-07T20:45:52Z</date>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>Closed</key>
        <false/>
        <key>CollocatedGroup</key>
        <array>
            <string>wifi.ssid.&lt;42554646 414c4f2d 43313143 3134&gt;</string>
        </array>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>LastConnected</key>
        <date>2016-10-07T20:46:51Z</date>
        <key>Passpoint</key>
        <false/>
        <key>PersonalHotspot</key>
        <false/>
        <key>PossiblyHiddenNetwork</key>
        <false/>
        <key>RoamingProfileType</key>
        <string>Multi</string>
        <key>SPRoaming</key>
        <false/>
        <key>SSID</key>
        <data>
        Q0lUWU1BWA==
        </data>
        <key>SSIDString</key>
        <string>CITYMAX</string>
        <key>SecurityType</key>
        <string>Open</string>
        <key>SystemMode</key>
        <true/>
        <key>TemporarilyDisabled</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
```

i tried playing around with those values (even deleting the entire key) but no luck.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would attempt would be to try going to the url of the default gateway.

If that does not work you will probably have to change your mac address. Most systems go off the network adapter's mac address.

Comment: Sadly I am not familiar with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings section of your mac, select Airport/WI-FI, you should see an ADVANCED button, click on it, then in the airport tab, select the citymax network click on “-”  (minus sign) . This should remove the network and ask you again for proper configuration.

Comment: Tried it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Some Captive Portal solutions set some cookies on the browser for session persistence. Try browsing on private mode to see if it works.

Comment: Already tried didn't work

Answer (score -3):

I discovered a way to force captive portal WiFi login page to load... opening the browser and typing in the address bar the URL `bing.com`

Not google and no other way but with `bing.com` and every time I have a hanging WiFi connection issue with captive portal login page not coming up or loading when I use `bing.com` I am met with a forced to login pop up or webpage load access.

Comment: Shameless plug for a bad search engine?